# check if a formfield is multiline or not using itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I need to check if a formfield (text field) is multiline or not using itextsharp. I have the following code but it doesn't seem to work. In the key I have the formfield name.

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary dic = new PdfDictionary();
dic = (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary)form.GetFieldItem(key).GetMerged(0);
//Check if textbox is multiline. If yes then do not truncate.
if (!(dic.GetAsNumber(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.FF) != null && dic.GetAsNumber(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.FF).IntValue == iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfFormField.FF_MULTILINE))
{
 //some code
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it didn't seem to work". What actually happened? Did you get an error message?

Comment: I mean if I set a formfield to multiline then also it goes inside the loop. It should not go since there is a check for multiline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When in doubt, check the [book](http://itextpdf.com/book), more specifically [chapter 13](http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C13) where you'll find an example called [InspectForm](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter13/InspectForm.cs) from which you can copy this code snippet.

```
flags = dict.GetAsNumber(PdfName.FF).IntValue;
if ((flags & BaseField.MULTILINE) > 0)
    sb.Append(" -> multiline");
```

The reason why your code doesn't work: your assumption that the `MULTILINE` flag is the only flag that is set. It most probably isn't. The FieldFlags (`FF`) value is a bitset and `MULTILINE` is responsible for only one bit in the set.